How can I use script.google.com or Google APIs to have a list of the last logins in google of a user?
I am trying to have last logins of a user in google platform using script.google.com but when I try with this sample:
https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/blob/main/adminSDK/reports/quickstart.gs
I only get old data. I have seen that there is much lag time for this event:
https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F7061566%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=7061566&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a
Anybody knows any way to have that info without lag?
I need that every user of a organization in google to receive an email with the last logins info each time the user logs in.
I tryed with this sample:
https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/blob/main/adminSDK/reports/quickstart.gs
function listLogins() {
  const userKey = 'all';
  const applicationName = 'login';
  const optionalArgs = {
    maxResults: 10
  };
  try {
    const response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
    const activities = response.items;
    if (!activities || activities.length === 0) {
      console.log('No logins found.');
      return;
    }
    // Print login events
    console.log('Logins:');
    for (const activity of activities) {
      console.log('%s: %s (%s)', activity.id.time, activity.actor.email,
          activity.events[0].name);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer)- Handle exception from the Report  API
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

But get old data
